# Unable to Load MSMdpump.dll

Tags: iis, ssas

I've been trying to set up Analysis Service. I've followed the step by step guide mentioned in the link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=sql-server-2017.

However, I'm still unable to configure this.

I'm getting following Errors in Browsers:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">


-<soap:Body>


-<soap:Fault xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<faultcode>XMLAnalysisError.0xc10e0002</faultcode>

<faultstring>Parser: The syntax for 'GET' is incorrect.</faultstring>


-<detail>

<Error HelpFile="" Source="Unknown" Description="Parser: The syntax for 'GET' is incorrect." ErrorCode="3238920194"/>

</detail>

</soap:Fault>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I have checked Event Log below is the error I could see:

```
The description for Event ID 25 from source MSOLAP ISAPI Extension: \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OLAP\msmdpump.dll cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

    If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

    The following information was included with the event: 

    msmdsrv.rll
    7177
```

Not sure if I'm missing something here..I've searched for this error however without any luck. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The msmdpump.dll does not service GET requests, only POST messages. When you browse to http://your-server/OLAP/msmdpump.dll this SOAP error is what you should expect to see. In the setup instructions you linked in your message, at the bottom you will see Step 6: Test your configuration. Item 3 is what you want to do next:

"In Management Studio, in the Connect to Server dialog box, select Analysis Services as the server type. In Server name, enter the HTTP address of the msmdpump extension: http://my-web-srv01/OLAP/msmdpump.dll."